# Eigenvalus and trace of matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Given matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. I have to find its eigenvalues and trace of the matrix $A^{2014}$. I found engenvalues: $2$, $1 + i$, $1 - i$ but I don't know how to do the second task. Can you help me?

Comment: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k.$  trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. writing the complex number $1 + i = \sqrt 2e^{i\pi/4}$ might  help.

Comment: @Abel is $\lambda^k$ an eigenvalue because $A$ can be diagonalised?

Comment: @Karl, it does not matter whether $A$ can be diagonlised or not. reason is if $Ax = \lambda x,$ then if you multiply by $A$ both sides you get $A^2x = \lambda Ax = \lambda^2 x$ and by induction for all integer $k.$

Comment: @Abel Thanks that helped. I had it in my head that powers of matrices are found with diagonal matrices and would have missed the point.

Answer (score 0):

we will use the fact that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A,$ then $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k.$  it helps to write $1\pm i = \sqrt 2e^{\pm i\pi/4}$ so that
$ (1\pm i)^{2014} = 2^{1007} e^{(i503\pi \pm \pi/2)}$.

so the eigenvalues of $A^{2014}$ are $\{2^{2014}, \pm 2^{1007}i \}$ and the trace of $A^{2014} = 2^{2014}$